# How to extract information from a file with key value pair

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a large number of txt file which contains information in a key value pair format

```
"Site Code": "LEYB"
"Also known as": ""
"Location": "Pier Site, Poblacion del Sur, Villaba, Southern Leyte"
"Contact person(s)": ""
"Coordinates[1]": "11 12 40.302622, 124 23 21.450632"
"Coordinates[2]": "11.211195, 124.389292"
"School ID": ""
"Site Description": "Benchmark LEYB is on end part of right side wall,leading to the seaport"
"Sketch": "./LEYB.docx"
"Constructed": "PHIVOLCS - October 2009"
"Method" : "Campaign"
```

All I want to do is to extract those information to create a master file. maybe in a column format such as csv, JSON or excel.

Can you suggest a tool or a file system strategy in Node.js that can achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Assuming file.txt is the file where you have the data in key value pair (but not in proper json format)

```
var fs = require("fs");
var content = fs.readFileSync("file.txt");
var lines = content.toString().split('\n');

var myObj = {};

for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
      var currentline = lines[line].split(':');
      myObj[currentline[0].trim().replace(/["]/g, "")] = currentline[1].trim().replace(/["]/g, "");
}

console.log(myObj);
```

This will give you a proper object which you can then use to convert to csv,json or whatever.

To convert to JSON use.

```
JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

Comment: it works well.. now that its in JSON format I can easily export the file to HTML tables etc.. thanks for your help'

Comment: I noticed that the script will also remove any single quotes from both the key as well as value, So I updated my answer.